# how to export object of functions to another object of function javascript (nuxt)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

in ***index.js***. This is working as expected

```
export default ({ $axios, target }) => () => ({
  async index({ endpoint }) { // Function that I want to reuse
    return await $axios.get(endpoint)
  },
  async specificFunction({ endpoint }) { // Function that is specific to this file
    return await $axios.get(endpoint/specific)
  },
})
```

but I want extract the index() function to another file for reusability

in ***shared.js***
I have tried

```
export default ({ $axios, target }) => () => ({
  async index({ endpoint }) { // Function that I want to reuse
    return await $axios.get(endpoint)
  }
})
```

I have also tried

```
export default ({ $axios, target }) => ({
  async index({ endpoint }) { // Function that I want to reuse
    return await $axios.get(endpoint)
  }
})
```

in ***index.js***

```
import sharedFunction from './shared.js'

    export default ({ $axios, target }) => () => ({
      ...sharedFunction,
      async specificFunction({ endpoint }) { // Function that is specific to this file
        return await $axios.get(endpoint/specific)
      },
    })
```

I did try different way when spreading the function

```
import sharedFunction from './shared.js'

    export default ({ $axios, target }) => () => ({
      ...sharedFunction($axios, target),
      // ...sharedFunction($axios, target)(),
      async specificFunction({ endpoint }) { // Function that is specific to this file
        return await $axios.get(endpoint/specific)
      },
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In shared.js:

```
export default ({ $axios, target }) => ({
  index: async ({ endpoint }) => await $axios.get(endpoint)
})
```

In index.js:

```
import shared from './shared.js'

export default ({ $axios, target }) => ({
  ...shared({ $axios, target }),
  async specificFunction({ endpoint }) { // Function that is specific to this file
    return await $axios.get(endpoint/specific)
  },
})
```